# Tikz: Position dodge on the x axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning

For my 2x2 factorial data, I want to create a line plot with confidence intervals in Tikz.
The x-axis ticks are supposed to have a small offset so that the confidence intervals of the two plots do not overlap each other (like *position_dodge* in ggplot2).

My current result looks quite like I want it:
[image: Current result in Tikz]

However, my code is extremely inelegant. I inserted an invisible plot to achieve that the x-axis ticks were centered between the data points (see code below).

My question is: Is there are more elegant way to achieve position dodging in Tikz, or even to create such line graphs in general?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid = major,
ylabel = Response time (ms),
xlabel = Prime valence,
xtick = data,
xmin = 0,
xmax = 1,
xticklabels = {negative,positive},
legend style = {at={(1.2,0.5)},
anchor = center}
]

\addplot[white] plot % invisible plot to center the labels
coordinates {
(0.25,750)
(0.75,750)
};
\addlegendentry{}

\addplot[red,mark=square*] plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
coordinates {
(0.22,769) +- (0,15) % manual dodge for each data point
(0.72,764) +- (0,15)
};
\addlegendentry{negative}

\addplot[green,mark=square*] plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
coordinates {
(0.28,746) +- (0,15)
(0.78,716) +- (0,15)
};
\addlegendentry{positive}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you attached to `pgfplots` for any reason? You could always plot it in R and use [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/)?

Comment: Also, welcome to TeX.SX! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I have two possible improvements:

1. your invisible plot has just one purpose, namely to collect the input for `xtick=data`. If you write `xtick={0.25,0.75}`, you do not need the invisible plot anymore. I do not know if you want to embed the solution into some more advanced solution in which you do not know the positions in advance... but for the minimal, this clearly solves the problem.
2. you have added the offsets manually to each coordinate. Alternatively, you can let `pgfplots` do that job by means of `x filter`, see the example below.

Here is the result with these two modifications:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid = major,
ylabel = Response time (ms),
xlabel = Prime valence,
xtick = {0.25,0.75},
xmin = 0,
xmax = 1,
xticklabels = {negative,positive},
legend style = {at={(1.2,0.5)},
anchor = center}
]

\addplot[red,mark=square*,
    % manual dodge for each data point
    x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-0.03}}
] plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
coordinates {
(0.25,769) +- (0,15) 
(0.75,764) +- (0,15)
};
\addlegendentry{negative}

\addplot[green,mark=square*,
    % manual dodge for each data point
    x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+0.03}}
] plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
coordinates {
(0.25,746) +- (0,15)
(0.75,716) +- (0,15)
};
\addlegendentry{positive}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]